# How to disable tooltip for a specific column of a webix datatable

Tags: javascript, datatable, tooltip, webix

I have a configured tooltip as 'true' in my datatable settings which is working as expected.
However, I want to deactivate the tooltip for a specific column of the datatable.
Lets assume columns which are having a button in its cell, the tooltip should not show up. Using onMouseMove and checking the class for the button, later on, I am trying to disable the tooltip as below: 
But it is not taking effect.

```
on:{
    onMouseMove:function(id, e, node) {
    //alert("this is mouse move = "+e.srcElement.className);
    var cls = e.srcElement.className;
    if(cls == 'btnclass') {
        $$('mytable').config.tooltip = false;
        //alert("disabled");
    }
    }
}
```

The entire snippet is here https://webix.com/snippet/79d05d47 
Can anybody help me make it work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no any direct option to disable the tooltip in webix datatable. While specifying the configuration of datatable, if you set property `tooltip=true`, it automatically applied to all the columns. But if you want it to disable for the particular column, you can specify the template for that column and in the template, you can remove the title attribute.

Comment: For the particular column, I am already using a template to show a button in all the cells coming under that. For the tooltip, I just mentioned tooltip:false and it got disabled for that particular column and keeping the tooltip for other columns as is. It worked for me. Can you show an example of what you are implying?